# What causes the difference in the twitter embeddings?

Tags: block-editor, embed, oembed, twitter

I noticed that the way WP sites embed tweets slightly different. To avoid issues when embedding tweets in my own site I'd like to understand the details.

**1) Embed in `<div class="oembed-cached">`**

```
<div class="oembed-cached">
  <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-width="550" data-dnt="true">
    <!-- Tweet contents ... -->
  </blockquote>
  <p>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

**2) Embed in `<figure class="wp-block-embed is-type-rich is-provider-twitter wp-block-embed-twitter">`**

```
<figure class="wp-block-embed is-type-rich is-provider-twitter wp-block-embed-twitter">
  <div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-width="550" data-dnt="true">
      <!-- Tweet content's ... -->
    </blockquote>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </div>
</figure>
```

What causes the different ways in embedding a tweet? Can it be that the cause are two different block types used by the respecting editor?